# Does representability of the subfunctor coherent with taking quotients?

Tags: commutative-algebra, category-theory, algebraic-number-theory, galois-representations

I'm currently learning the deformation of Galois representations by reading [Gouvêa's note](https://typo.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/fileadmin/_migrated/media/Gouvea-2001-Deformations_of_Galois_representations.pdf).

Let $\mathsf{CNL}$ be the category of complete noetherian local rings with (fixed) residue field $\mathbb{F}$. The morphisms are local homomorphisms fixing the residue field. Let $\Lambda \in \mathsf{CNL}$ and denote the full subcategory of $\Lambda$-algebras in $\mathsf{CNL}$ by $\mathsf{CNL}_{\Lambda}$. The full subcategory of artinian objects are denoted by $\mathsf{Ar}_{\Lambda}$.

Let $\mathbf{F}: \mathsf{Ar}_{\Lambda} \rightarrow \mathsf{Set}$ be a functor and $\mathbf{F}_1$ a subfunctor of $\mathbf{F}$. By a "subfunctor", we mean for all $A \in \mathsf{Ar}_{\Lambda}$, $\mathbf{F}_1(A) \subseteq \mathbf{F}(A)$. (More precise definitions here: [Subfunctor in nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/subfunctor))

Now suppose $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{F}_1$ are pro-representable, i.e. they are represented by object in
$\mathsf{CNL}_{\Lambda}$. Let $R, R_1 \in \mathsf{CNL}_{\Lambda}$  represent  $\mathbf{F}$ and $\mathbf{F}_1$ accordingly, then one can show that $R_1$ is a quotient of $R$. Say $R_1 = R/I$.

Let $A \in \mathsf{Ar}_{\Lambda}$ and $a \in \mathbf{F}_1(A) \subseteq \mathbf{F}(A)$ fixed. Then for $a$,

1. By representability of $\mathbf{F}_1$, there exists a corresponding homomorphism $\phi_{1,a}: R_1 \rightarrow A$.   (Via $\mathbf{F}_1(A) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(R_1, A)$.)
2. By representability of $\mathbf{F}$, there exists a corresponding homomorphism $\phi_{a}: R \rightarrow A$.   (Via $\mathbf{F}(A) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(R, A)$.)

**My main question is: Are the two homomorphisms $\phi_{1,a}$ and $\phi_{a}$ "coherent"?**

To be more specific, let $\pi: R \rightarrow R_1=R/I$ be the natural homomorphism. **Is the composition
$$ R \stackrel{\pi}{\longrightarrow} R/I \stackrel{\phi_{1,a}}{\longrightarrow} A $$
EXACTLY the homomorphism $\phi_{a}$**?

I feel like this is correct but I have spent quite a long time struggling for a neat proof but failed. So I'm sitll doubting whether this is really true or not?

Thank you all for commenting and answering!

Comment: The post https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1194264/direct-proof-of-the-dual-statement-of-the-yoneda-lemma?rq=1, especially the comments by Zhen Lin helped a lot as well for my understanding on @curious math guy 's answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Yoneda embedding associates to any natural transformation $\text{Hom}(R_1,-)\to \text{Hom}(R,-)$ a ring morphism $\pi:R \to R_1$ such that for any $T$
$$\text{Hom}(R_1,T)\to \text{Hom}(R,T),\quad\phi\mapsto \phi\circ \pi$$
is the morphism induced by the natural transformation. Choose an arbitrary $a\in F_1(A)$
given by $\phi_{1,a}\in \text{Hom}(R_1,A).$ Then its image under the inclusion of the subfunctor, by definition of the induced ring morphism $R\to R_1$, is given by the image of $\phi_{1,a}$ under $\text{Hom}(R_1,T)\to \text{Hom}(R,T)$, i.e its $\phi_{1,a}\circ \pi$. Hence $\phi_{1,a}\circ \pi=\phi_a$ to use your notation.

Comment: Thank you so much for your great help! :) So it seems that the key point is that the yoneda embedding is a full, faithful functor by yoneda lemma.